# Read wav file from python and convert frames into RAW s16le string

Tags: python, audio, librosa

I'm reading a file in Python using either of librosa, wave or soundfile libraries and I need to push the chunk (any size) to a HTTP stream. By specification, stream string input requires me to convert frames into RAW s16le format.

I tried multiple options including:

```
soundarray,rate = librosa.load(pathToWavFile, dtype="<i2")
str = b''.join(soundarray)
```

But this just creates an empty audio stream. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you open to other `python` audio libraries or you need to work with `librosa` ?

Comment: @Anil_M, for now any library can work. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: @ Andrey Shtylenko , check my response and see if it's useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/API.markdown) to convert audio to audio-segment, split audio-segment into chunks  that are playable (i.e you can play each chunk), then convert them to raw as needed.

Here is a quick code.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.utils import make_chunks

myaudio = AudioSegment.from_file("myaudio.wav" , "wav") 
chunk_length_ms = 1000 # pydub calculates in millisec
chunks = make_chunks(myaudio, chunk_length_ms) #Make chunks of one sec

#Convert chunks to raw audio data which you can then feed to HTTP stream
for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
    raw_audio_data = chunk.raw_data
```

By default raw audio is 16bit

```
>>> 
bytes_per_sample= 2  # 2 byte (16 bit) samples
```

Since `raw_audio_data` is raw, if above format doesn't work, you can convert to any other format as needed. Check [pydub utils api](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/pydub/utils.py) for details.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get raw data from a wav file in one go, then [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub) can also be used like this:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

sound = AudioSegment.from_wav('your_audio.wav')  # can do same for mp3 and other formats

raw = sound._data  # returns byte string 

print(raw)  # prints "b'k\xffe\xffw\xff\x83\xffu\xff\x85\xff\x81\xff\x85\xff\xa5....."
```