# Convert wav file to 16 bit raw signed raw and little endian form without using sox

Tags: python, wav, sox

I am trying to convert mono channeled wav file to 16 bit raw file, more specifically the SOX command that is given below:

```
sox_cmd = 'sox {} --type raw --bits 16 --channels 1 --rate {} --encoding signed-integer --endian little --compression 0.0 --no-dither - '.format(quote(audio_path), desired_sample_rate)
```

I cannot use this in Windows because it requires installation of sox by altering path variables and all which cannot be done in an installation package. So, I want python code that can do the same task and can return a numpy array of raw data.

Currently, I am doing it like this:

```
import sounddevice as sd
from scipy.io.wavfile import write

fs = 44100  # Sample rate
seconds = 3  # Duration of recording

myrecording = sd.rec(int(seconds * fs), samplerate=fs, channels=1)   #record as mono channeled
sd.wait()  # Wait until recording is finished
write('output.wav', fs, myrecording)  # Save as WAV file 

from scipy.io.wavfile import read
import numpy as np

from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.utils import make_chunks

myaudio = AudioSegment.from_file("output.wav" , "wav") 
chunk_length_ms = 1000 # pydub calculates in millisec
chunks = make_chunks(myaudio, chunk_length_ms) #Make chunks of one sec

#Convert chunks to raw audio data which you can then feed to HTTP stream
for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):

    raw_audio_data = chunk.raw_data
raw_audio_data=np.array(raw_audio_data)
raw_audio_data.shape   # prints "()"
```

Any help on this will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read wav file from python and convert frames into RAW s16le string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46326922/read-wav-file-from-python-and-convert-frames-into-raw-s16le-string)

Comment: I am actually using "that^" solution in my question and it is not working as expected.

Comment: ok. shouldn't the last 3 statements of the code be indented?

Comment: yes, done that, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Have you tried installing ffmpeg from [here](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-windows)? I ran your script after installing ffmpeg and adding the path to the System Path. I got no errors at least. An output file was generated.

Comment: yes it is installed already, are you talking about 'output.wav' being generated? The process of recording audio and converting to mono channeled file is working fine. But the "raw_audio_data" is not being generated. More specifically, the SOX command is not being replaced by python code.